# How can I validate a filename after selecting it?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-file-input

I am using bootstrap file input from here:

https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput

and I am trying to validate a filename after selecting a file.
I tried this:

```
$("#mytest").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "./upload.php",
    uploadAsync: true,      
    showPreview: false,    
    language: 'it',
    elErrorContainer: "#errorBlock"    

  })
.on('filebatchpreupload', function(event, data, id, index) {    
      return {
          message: "wrong file",
          data: {}
      };      
      });
```

and it works, but then it disable itself and I cannot do anything else.

I have noticed it does not happen if showPreview:true

I guess it's a bug? Any idea to what's happening and if it's there a workaround?

thank you!

Comment: According to [the doc](https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-events#filebatchselected) your `data` variable should contain the list of `File`s, and their respective name, if following the browser [`File` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

Comment: if i use the filebatchselected and I write inside: return {
       message: "wrong file",
        data: files
      };   nothing happens